# How can I make an Emacs shell command output buffer always follow the bottom?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm writing an Emacs minor mode that has some Emacs commands which invoke shell commands. I'm using the following code:

```
    (let ((output (get-buffer-create "*Foo Output*")))
      (start-process "Foo Process" output argv0)
      (display-buffer output))
```

I'd like the buffer containing those shell commands to automatically scroll to the bottom any time output is inserted, or at the very least when the command is finished executing. How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by using a [process filter function](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Filter-Functions.html#Filter-Functions).

> A process filter function is a function that receives the standard
>   output from the associated process. If a process has a filter, then
>   all output from that process is passed to the filter. The process
>   buffer is used directly for output from the process only when there is
>   no filter.
>
> [...]
>
> Many filter functions sometimes (or always) insert the output in the
>   process's buffer, mimicking the actions of Emacs when there is no
>   filter.

`start-process` returns a process object that stands for the new subprocess in Lisp which you can store in a variable, say `proc`. You can write a simple filter function that just inserts the output of the process into the associated output buffer, thereby moving `point` to the end of the buffer.

```lisp
(defun my-insertion-filter (proc string)
  (when (buffer-live-p (process-buffer proc))
    (with-current-buffer (process-buffer proc)
      ;; Insert the text, advancing the process marker.
      (goto-char (process-mark proc))
      (insert string)
      (set-marker (process-mark proc) (point)))))
```

Use `set-process-filter` to assign that filter function to your process.

```lisp
(set-process-filter proc 'my-insertion-filter)
```

Alternatively, if it's sufficient to only jump to the end of the buffer once the process has terminated, you might want to use a [sentinel](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sentinels.html#Sentinels).

> A process sentinel is a function that is called whenever the
>   associated process changes status for any reason, including signals
>   (whether sent by Emacs or caused by the process's own actions) that
>   terminate, stop, or continue the process. The process sentinel is also
>   called if the process exits.

```
(defun my-sentinel (proc event)
  (when (buffer-live-p (process-buffer proc))
    (with-current-buffer (process-buffer proc)
      (end-of-buffer))))
```

(Note that this function scrolls to the end of the process buffer every time it is called which may happen not only at the end of the process. If you *really* only want it to do that when the process has terminated, check if `event` is the string `"finished\n"`.)

Use `set-process-sentinel` to assign that sentinel to your process.

```lisp
(set-process-sentinel proc 'my-sentinel)
```

Comment: I have a variant of this question. I am using a global-set-key in my .emacs to make a certain key combination run a shell command (via the shell-command function). I have the same problem as the OP; I only see the top of *Shell Command Output*, not the bottom. I blindly typed the above process-filter stuff into my .emacs file and I get a warning "Symbol's value as variable is void: proc" coming from the set-process-filter command. I assume that proc is supposed to be the name of the process associated to the shell's buffer but I have 0 lisp knowledge. Am I supposed to be runningthecmdvia M-x?

Comment: @KevinBuzzard Your problem is too complex to be answered in a comment, consider asking a proper question to allow for more elaborate answers.